# C# Process.Start Causing AccessViolationException Randomly

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have been tackling this issue for 3 months now.

Error I am Getting in Native Debugging:

> "Exception thrown at 0x5A222FC2 (comct123.dll) in FileReader.exe:
> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000C."

Normal Debug:

> 'System.AccessVioliationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

My setup is really simple:

```
public static Form_Interface Interface;

public static void Initialize()
{
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Interface = new Form_Interface();
    Interface.Filesdgv.DataSource = File.SortableBindingList;
    Application.Run(Interface);
}
```

Seems simple enough, right? No.
So basically I have a simple Event that simply opens the file using Process.Start() and no matter what I do it will randomly crash with 'System.AccessVioliationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll here:

```
private void Filesdgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Filesdgv.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

            if (rowIndex >= 0)
            {
                int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
                File file = (File)((DataGridView)sender).Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem;

                switch (columnIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            Process.Start(file.Location);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // This fking catch never works anyway.
        }
    }));
}

private void FileInterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string oCurrent in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "Files To Check")))
        if (oCurrent.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            new File(oCurrent.Split('\\').Last(), oCurrent);
}
```

It doesn't matter if I am opening files/links or anything else, it still behaves in the same way.
The link and file location is a readonly field as well.

I have many other uses for reading row data and it never crashes, even if i spam click 10000 times, It will only crash randomly with Process.Start()

Things I tried:

- Using BeginInvoke
- Using Invoke
- Not Using Invoke/BeginInvoke
- Putting File Link into a string before reading it.
- Using multiple Try Catch
- Recoded on another machine... same results there aswell.
- I tried using File.Open (either doesn't open the file or throws same error lmao)
- Tried using [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions], still won't catch the exception.
- Dosen't matter if i click slow or fast still 1/30 chance it happens.
- Tried Putting Task.Run(() => Process.Start()); you'd think that a thread will protect you from an exception? no still crashes...

[image]

File Class looks like this:

```
public class File
{
    public static SortableBindingList<File> SortableBindingList = new SortableBindingList<File>(new List<File>());
    public readonly string fileName;
    public readonly string filePath;
    
    public void AddRow()
    {
        Client.Interface.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            lock (SortableBindingList)
                if (!SortableBindingList.Contains(this))
                    SortableBindingList.Add(this);
        }));
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return fileName;
        }
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return filePath;
        }
    }
    public File(string fileName, string filePath)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        AddRow();
    }
}
```

Initalize() is called in static void Main(string[] args) btw.
There are no other threads running editing stuff or anything like that, the only thread running is the form thread. which waits for user input.

Solutions I am looking for:

- Alternative Method to launch files/hyperlinks.
- A way to avoid form crashing (try catch style)

Crashes even with static data!:
[image]

Other threads running although these were not started by me.
[image]

Comment: You should give context to the snippet you've presented here.  - When / where is `Initialize()` called? What calls it? What is a `List<File>`? What fills it and with what? Why did you store a static instance of a Form? Why did you change the access modifier of a child Control? -- Why on earth are you using `Invoke()` in an event handler, with the same Control that raised the event? Why are you trying to invoke at all? -- `Thread.Run()` doesn't exist, you mean `Task.Run()` -- It looks like you end up dereferencing a null pointer somewhere, the missing context may explain where / what causes it.

Comment: Added more detail, using invokes, as I had no clue what the issue was, but you're right I don't need them. and yes I meant Task.Run()

Comment: Still missing: what fills the (`static`) BindingList and when / how, since it's initialized empty? Why is that Form declared `static`? Why is the access modifier of the DGV set to `public`? Are you trying to access that Control from somewhere else? Is this Form accessed from anywhere else? If so, from where? -- If you remove the static declaration and you simply pass the BindingList to a Constructor of that Form  (adding one that accepts a `SortableBindingList` object), what does this change in the current operations?

Comment: Edited Initialize(), i needed them public at some point as i had more Properties in the File class to return detected language etc but I removed that completely now. oh I also add rows using Invoke. lemme add that to the thing sec.

Comment: Ok done, sorry I had to go between 2 versions i wrote from scratch, one is on an rdp i can't copy from so i had to manually type most of it.

Comment: The loop you have now added, after `Application.Run()`, is irrelevant, since that's executed only after the Form closes and the application with it -- It looks like you have data coming from a/different Thread(s) and you're trying to update a DataGridView, using a static instance of a Form, with a collection that is not Thread-safe; that's why you're trying to `Invoke()` something (not just useless, very *dangerous*) -- Remove the `static` Form instance to begin with, all goes from there -- There's no surprise this all fails -- Not getting into how the `File` class is constructed.

Comment: Take a look at the [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) interface and the [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class as a possible surrogate. You can find many example of its use here.

Comment: look at last image i added it literally crashes on google.com, there are no other threads running as well as i said.

Comment: Usually when the crash happens it lags for 3-4 sec, its way more common to crash on slow computers i realized.

Comment: Every hard-to-diagnose crash starts with a bad theory of the problem.  The dll is not named "comct123.dll", what little we can see of the crucial stack trace shows no evidence that Process.Start() is the cause.  Also the reason that *catch* does nothing. 
 We can just barely see a [DllImport] declaration, bad pinvoke is always a good explanation for AVE.

Comment: In the File class you have:  `Client.Interface.Invoke((Action)(() => { lock (SortableBindingList) [...] }));` <- What are you invoking for then? Why are you trying to set a lock? If you're Invoking from the same Thread, you have a problem. The exception is caused by `ComCtl32.dll` -- Remove the static instance of that Form and re-set the access modified of the DGV to `private` -- Do you have some *customizations* in some Controls? -- Also, as Hans noted, what are you PInvoking?

Comment: The files are loaded on FileInterface_Load event, btw, added that in.

Comment: Well, add row only happens once when form is loaded, there is no problem with that. There are no crashes on load, only when the click event occurs. And click event does not include any static references, but just asks windows kindly to open google.com, I don't see why invoking or even locking would be a problem elsewhere, i did as suggested and made it private etc it still behaves in the same way. it would never ever crash if i commented that process.start out. so....

Comment: I just spam clicked 1000 times with no process start and no crashes at all, here there is something wrong with it. I have multiple apps using similar model and every one of them crashes on Process.Start for some unholy reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 100% fix for this error is to use:
`Application.EnableVisualStyles();`

Because this is a known problem in comctl32.dll v5. When application uses VisualStyles, it forces load on comctl32.dll v6, which has this issues fixed.
I found solution while reading this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/402
The cause of the issue was using Process.Start() which uses  unsafe native Windows DLLs API functions, which are 32 BIT and unsafe even stacktrace called it unsafe:

```
StackTrace  "at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)\r\n..."
```

I tackled this issue for over a year over something so stupid... my app must have crashed more than 1000 times and it takes 2 min each time to load :(, why would microsoft leave such stupid bugs is beyond me.